Merge Extensions
Let say we have a field F and an extension $F\subseteq K$.
In some cases we can merge an extension of the form $F(a_1,a_2)$ into a simple one $F(a_3)$
where $a_1,a_2,a_3\in K $.
For instance $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$.
So my question is when are we able to merge such an extension $F(a_1,a_2)$ into a simple one $F(a_3)$?

We also need that $[F:K]$ is finite. There is no primitive element for $F=\overline{\Bbb  Q}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

We always can when the extension is separable, which is always the case for fields of characteristic $0$. See Primitive element theorem.
